# Github and should i use it?

Tags: git, github

i am just expanding my tools for Web Development and i have come across Github and Git which i have been little scared to start on.

My jobs consist of Developing Websites to modifying existing sites design or functionality.

I am presuming git and github would be used for a Full Web Development form Scratch, am i right?
Are you meant to use github as a way for the client to have access to the project too?

Anyway sorry for the noob question i just have no idea how to incorporate Git or Github into my existing workflow.

Comment: If you currently work on a file for a while and then save it as, say, `indexV1.html`, then come back later and save `indexV2.html`, then maybe later you go back and change the first one and save it as new file `indexV1a.html`, you are already using a haphazard form of version control and git (or one of the competing version control systems) will change the way you work entirely (for the better!).

Comment: "Too broad"? I think "primarily opinion-based" would have been a better reason for closing the question.

Answer (score 2):

`git` is a [version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). It's probably the most popular these days and something that you, as a developer, will benefit from knowing well. Version control is a good practice in general and you should be using some software to do it. Git is an alternative and, as I said above, one of the most popular ones.

`github` is a company who provides a git hosting service and a few value adds (like integrated bug tracking, scheduling, wiki etc.) that are useful when you're doing larger projects and collaborating with other developers.

Answer (score 1):

`git` is a Distributed Version Control System. It can store a history of your changes, distribute your code to remote repositories, let you experiment with new code without worrying about breaking existing code, and much more.

GitHub is an example of git repository hosting, that allows you to conveniently share your code and collaborate on it with other people. There are many other options like BitBucket, GitLab, CloudForge, CodeBase, etc. GitHub is definitely the most popular for public/open-source projects.

Since you want to use it for work, you probably want to keep the repo private. GitHub makes you pay for private repos but BitBucket and GitLab offer private repos for free as long as you don't have too many collaborators on the private repo.

You normally wouldn't use it to show stuff to your clients unless they're technically inclined, Git repos are primarily for sharing the actual code, not demos. However, since you asked about web development, GitHub does offer GitHub Pages which allows you to demo static sites completely free with no restrictions.